# How to group several Google Calendars into one calendar without creating a new user account?

Tags: google-calendar

I want to display a few of the important calendars on a T.V. screen on permanent display.

Certain meetings and holidays, and people's scheduled vacations, for example:

It seems that one option is to create a new google account, companycalendar@example.com, and then it can display whichever calendars we want it to. But it seems dumb to create a whole new account for this.

Is there any other way?